# SCCM 2007 R2 missing boot.wim files from OSD\Boot folder

Tags: sccm, wim, sccm-2007

I have just installed SCCM 2007 R2 and when I went to deploy an OS i found that there is a problem with the boot.wim...There isnt one in the osd\ folder on the SCCM server.
I then tried to use other WIM files and they all failed with "Error: Errors
    You can not import this boot image. Only finalized boot images are supported"
I even tried to recreate the wim with DISM and it still would not accept it.
Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the OSD stuff in SCCM actually come with boot.wim files you can use?  Or is it like regular WDS where you need to import the boot.wim files from regular OS installation media.  I haven't played with the OSD stuff in SCCM, but I run standalone WDS servers and I imported my boot.wim files from our new Win7 and Server 2008 R2 media.  You can also use Vista and Server 2008 media.  But the newer the better usually.

I think the other option is to use something like WAIK or MDT (which uses WAIK).  That'll give you the tools to create a custom boot.wim.

Comment: I found the solution. It was because I hadnt installed SP2 and i was trying to use a win 7 wim which I believe it wasnt picking up as a valid WIM.